# Hybrid Orbitals

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, schroedinger-equation, orbitals, quantum-chemistry

https://glossary.periodni.com/glossary.php?page=41&en=high+fructose pictures like the ones in this article make no sense to me.

I understand that we can take solutions to the Schrödinger equation and make normalised linear combinations to get new solutions. But how do we combine the spherically symmetric 2s solution with the 1px, 1py, 1pz solutions which are symmetric in the x, y and z planes respectively to form sp3 solutions that only show cylindrical symmetry?

Wikipedia says that the sp3 orbitals are 25% 2s orbitals and 75% p orbitals which makes sense but I don't see how that makes for such asymmetrical orbitals.

I can't believe I'm having such difficulties finding information about this

Comment: It is unclear in the images if they are the mod-squares or the real part. One needs to keep in mind that orbitals are complex valued functions.

Comment: Since we're only dealing with stationary states you could in neither case make these asymmetric solutions

Comment: OMG I got it... The P orbital does NOT show planar symmetry because one side is positive while the other is negative. So adding the spherically symmetric S orbital reduces one side and increase the other. How trivial...

Comment: Great! A detailed graph often solves many a misunderstandings while an under detailed one creates more! :)

Comment: @StijnBoshoven If you now know the answer it would be useful to write an answer so that the system no longer has an unanswered question on it's books !

Answer (score 2):

The P orbital does NOT show planar symmetry because one side is positive while the other is negative. So adding the spherically symmetric S orbital reduces one side and increases the other.

Comment: [Here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_Chem1_(Lower)/09%3A_Chemical_Bonding_and_Molecular_Structure/9.06%3A_The_Hybrid_Orbital_Model)'s a text that corroborates your finding, also providing some pictures of this combination of orbitals.